# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error when I try to create an instance of this class?

Tags: java, class, instance, public, cannot-find-symbol

So I'm a bit rusty when it comes to Java, its been a few years since I've used it. One of the biggest issues I've been having is trying to use classes that I call from another file. both files are in the same directory, but I still get a "cannot find symbol" error. can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

here is my main class in Plantmain.java

```
public class Plantmain
{

  public static void main( String[] args)
    {
      Plant plantObj = new Plant();
    plantObj.Message();
 }

}
```

and this is the class its trying to call from Plant.java

```
    public class Plant
    {

    public void Message()
    {
      System.out.println("this is working");
    }


 }
```

Comment: How are you compiling the files?  This happens if you haven't compiled both of the .java files.  Try running `javac *.java` from your directory and then running it again (`java Plantmain`).

Comment: Check your coding convention also ;). Java use camelCase for function ;)

Comment: I'm running  javac * java from my directory

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put `Plant` into a package

and then put this into `Plantmain`

```
import myPackage.Plant;
```